# quotient topology and equivalence relation

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ be endowed with the topology

$$\mathcal{T}=\{X, \emptyset, \{a,b\}, \{c\}, \{a,b,c\}, \{d,e\}, \{a,b,d,e\}, \{c,d,e\}\}.$$

Let ~ be the equivalence relation on $X$ such that a~d. Describe the quotient topology on X/~. i.e. write down all the open sets.

I tried to define a surjectiion $f:X \rightarrow X/$~. Then we have f(a)=f(d)=a. But what's next? I have no idea how the assumption a~d helps, please help.

Comment: Find out for wich set $S\subset\{a,b,c,e\}$ its preimage under $f$ is open in $X$. The sets for which that is the case are exactly the open sets in $X/\sim$

Comment: You have to look at the definition of the quotient topology to start with. Have you done that? Write it down, and see how it applies to your specific case. You have an especially simple finite toplogy, so you can even write down all of the subsets of the spaces in question.

Answer (score 1):

Since $a$ and $d$ are the only points identified, we may write $X/\sim$ as the
four-point set $\{ad,b,c,e\}$, with the identification $f(a)=f(d)=ad$, $f(x)=x$ for
$x=b,c,e$.  $U\subseteq X/\sim$ is open in the quotient topology iff $f^{-1}[U]$ is open in $X$.  So let's check whether $U=\{ad,e\}$ is open in $X/\sim$.  Since $f^{-1}[U]=\{a,d,e\}\not\in\mathcal{T}$, $U$ is not open in $X/\sim$.  On the other hand, $V=\{ad,b,e\}$ is open in $X/\sim$ because $f^{-1}[V]=\{a,b,d,e\}\in\mathcal{T}$.